# How to provide arguments to resolveCodeLens in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to the example of a Visual Studio Code extension (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/codelens-sample) it is possible to resolve code lens:

```
public resolveCodeLens(codeLens: vscode.CodeLens, token: vscode.CancellationToken) {
        if (vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("codelens-sample").get("enableCodeLens", true)) {
            codeLens.command = {
                title: "Codelens provided by sample extension",
                tooltip: "Tooltip provided by sample extension",
                command: "codelens-sample.codelensAction",
                arguments: ["Argument 1", false]
            };
            return codeLens;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code lens displays next to a line of text in the editor window.

But it does not show any information dependant on the line.

I would like to pass the line of text to display in the codeLens command title. To create multiple custom messages.

How to provide a text "next" to codeLens displays to resolveCodeLens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same need to display line contextual information. Inspecting the constructor for `CodeLens` it accepts the command object in the second parameter.

[Codelens constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vEOc.png)

here is a snippet based on my implementation to solve this:

```js
    provideCodeLenses(document, token) {
        this.codeLenses = [];
        const regex = new RegExp("^[156789].*$");
        let lines = document.getText().split("\n");
        lines.forEach((lineText, lineNumber) => {
            if (regex.test(lineText)) {
                const position = new vscode.Position(lineNumber, 0);
                const range = new vscode.Range(position, position);
                let command = {
                   command = "",
                   title = "<your custom title based on lineText>"
                };
                this.codeLenses.push(new vscode.CodeLens(range, command));
            }
        });
        return this.codeLenses;
    }
```

Comment: However, according to the offical sample (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/codelens-sample) and doc, for performance reasons the creation of a code lens and resolving should be done to two stages, but since the resolveCodeLens seems to only process one codelens, it confuses me if I have multiple codelens.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends vscode.CodeLens to achieve this:

```
class CodeLensEx extends vscode.CodeLens {
    document: vscode.TextDocument;
    type: CodeLensExType;

    constructor(document: vscode.TextDocument,
        type: CodeLensExType,
        range: vscode.Range,
        command?: vscode.Command) {
        super(range, command);

        this.document = document;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and change the param type in your implementation (you can also cast manually):

```
public provideCodeLenses(document: vscode.TextDocument, token: vscode.CancellationToken): CodeLensEx[] | Thenable<CodeLensEx[]>
public resolveCodeLens(codeLens: CodeLensEx, token: vscode.CancellationToken)
```

then you can pass the info, code runs after getting info without crash:
[debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svvlE.png)